# Java call base method from base constructor

Tags: java, inheritance

How to call Super::printThree from Super::Super()?
In the example below I call Test::printThree instead.

```
class Super {
        Super() { 
        printThree(); // I want Super::printThree here!
        }
        void printThree() { System.out.println("three"); }
}
class Test extends Super {
        int three = 3
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Test t = new Test();
                t.printThree();
        }
        void printThree() { System.out.println(three); }
}

output:
0    //Test::printThree from Super::Super()
3    //Test::printThree from t.printThree()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't - it's a method which has been overridden in the subclass; you can't force a non-virtual method call. If you want to call a method non-virtually, either make the method private or final.

In general it's a bad idea to call a non-final method within a constructor for precisely this reason - the subclass constructor body won't have been executed yet, so you're effectively calling a method in an environment which hasn't been fully initialized.

Comment: I know this answer was posted long back but why does `printThree` of the Subclass get called even when it is invoked by the constructor of the Supercalss? Is it only because the reference variable of the object is of type Subclass? Is there detailed documentation on how this works? I only found a short sentence(2nd paragraph from the end) mentioned here https://dev.java/learn/inheritance/polymorphism/. I'm fairly new to Java. Thanks.

Comment: @Elben: Even during a constructor call, the object type is "whatever the final type will be" (so `Test` in this case). It doesn't change type during construction.

Answer (score 1):

You're violating the whole idea behind dynamic dispatching and inheritance here. Just don't do it (and it's pretty hard to circumvent in java anyhow). Instead make the function private and/or final so that it can't be overwritten in the inherited class

Answer (score 1):

If `Super` needs to ensure that `printThree()` isn't overridden, that method needs to be declared as `final`. Alternatively, the overriding method in `Test` can decide to call the overriden method if it chooses:

```
@Override
void printThree() { super.printThree(); }
```

If the base class doesn't mark a method as `final`, it's giving up the right not to have deriving classes override it and do as they please.

Comment: Except that he doesn't want to call the super method in the inherited class but the other way round. So the idea with `super` obviously won't work, because the super for his Super class is Object.

Comment: @Voo - agreed, I'm just pointing out the possible scenarios. What he wants isn't possible.