# How to test constructor with this() invocation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

Here is my class. I need to test this parametrized constructor `A(String param)`.

```
public class A {
    private String superParam;
    private Integer value;

    public A(String param) {
        this();
        append(param);
    }

    public A() {
        this.value = 100; 
    }

    public void append(String additionalParam) {
        this.superParam.concat(additionalParam);
    }        
}
```

Now I'm struggling with `this()` invocation. I would be appriciated for any suggestions.

*UPD:*

I also want to know how can I mock a method during constructor invocation when the object isn't created?

Comment: Check if `value` is 100.

Comment: Yes, but in this case I'm checking another constructor.

Comment: Im confused about what you are struggling with. Please be more specific

Comment: What _specifically_ do you want to test?

Comment: I need to check this() invocation.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Actually I need to test whole class.

Comment: Well, what is the side-effect of `this()`?

Comment: It fires `A()` constructor.

Comment: Note that `this.superParam.concat(additionalParam)` doesn't do anything. It creates a concatenated string but doesn't assign it to anything, so it has no effect. Strings in Java are immutable. Also, it is generally a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138397/calling-method-from-constructor) to call a [non-final method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477553/in-java-is-there-a-legitimate-reason-to-call-a-non-final-method-from-a-class-co) from a [constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223435/java-call-base-method-from-base-constructor) in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that, unless you make `value` publicly accessible (by changing its access modifier or providing a getter method), you can't test that `this()` is called.

However, you shouldn't really be checking that `this()` is called. Your tests should define the behaviour of the class by observing changes in its state, or the changes it makes on other classes, given specific input.

In this situation, you need to ask yourself what becomes different when class `A` is instantiated with its `String param` constructor, and that's what you need to check for in your tests. In your example, `value` isn't used anywhere, but in the actual code that this example comes from, it likely has some influence on the behaviour of the class that you can check on to verify (indirectly) that `this()` was called. If it doesn't, it's either redundant, or you need to refactor to make your class more testable.

Answer (score 0):

Using a standalone `main()` method test,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  A a = new A("Hello");
  assert(a.value == 100);
}
```

I noticed that your code here threw a `NullPointerException`

```
this.superParam.concat(additionalParam);
```

And, while irrelevant to testing the `this()`, you should assign the result of that operation (which you must do explicitly because Java String(s) are immutable),

```
this.superParam = this.superParam.concat(additionalParam);
```

(You might also have changed `superParam` to a `StringBuilder`, and `concat()` to `append()`). anyway your original version
, so I would change

```
private String superParam;
```

to

```
private String superParam = "";
```

Since the assertion did not fail, and since `a.value` was not `null`, the `this()` constructor was called. Nothing else sets `a.value` in your code.

Comment: You fixed the `NullPointerException` but the expression still has no effect. It creates a concatenated string and discards it, since it isn't assigned to anything. **Strings are immutable in Java.** (I know you know that.)

Comment: @DavidConrad Good to note. Edited. I also added in the alternative of `StringBuilder`.